# What are the GCP AIM permissions needed in order for an user to reply to users reviews on Google Workspace Marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-apps-marketplace

I need to provide some permissions to an user in order to reply to
the reviews on Google Workspace Marketplace, however when following a "[Reply to user reviews](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reply-to-reviews)" documentation I found, it says that I need to provide the Project Editor access to this user just for her to be able to reply to these reviews. As you could imagine, I can't do that otherwise this user will have an excess of unnecessary permissions, which could be dangerous.

**What I need**

Is there any way that I can provide just the necessary permissions for any user to reply to reviews? Is there any way to create a Custom Role on GCP IAM? If so, what are the necessary granular permission should I give?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure which permissions are required. Review the roles that start with **commerceprice** and **consumerprocurement**. If you list the permissions in **roles/editor**, you might see which permissions are related to marketplace.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have done that already and I have not found anything related to Marketplace. There are more than 4K permissions to go through.

Comment: When creating a question, include information on what you have already tried. What was the result when you created a custom role with **commerceprice** and **consumerprocurment** permissions? Also consider opening a support ticket with Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

### For a user to reply to users reviews on Google Workspace Marketplace you need the `basic.editor` or `basic.owner` permission

You can find this information in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reply-to-reviews#add_a_reply_to_a_user_review):

> To reply to a review, you must have basic.editor or basic.owner permission on the app's Google Cloud project. Follow the below steps to reply to a review.